# SKAudioNode Crash: AVAudioPlayerNode.mm:333: Start: required condition is false: _engine->IsRunning()

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit, skaudionode

I've a simple SKAudioNode:

`let backgroundSound = SKAudioNode(fileNamed: "backgroundSound.mp3")`

I use to play `backgroundSound.runAction(SKAction.play())` and `backgroundSound.runAction(SKAction.stop())` to stop.

Everything works fine until the app did enter in background mode and I'll resume more than 3 minute.
If I go in background mode and resume after 10 - 20 seconds, the Audio doesn't crash.

All crash log:

```
2016-05-29 23:26:43.612 PippiPompiere[1070:199471] 23:26:43.611 ERROR:    [0x3a7cf000] AVAudioPlayerNode.mm:333: Start: required condition is false: _engine->IsRunning()
2016-05-29 23:26:43.616 PippiPompiere[1070:199471] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'required condition is false: _engine->IsRunning()'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x23ba5b8b 0x23362dff 0x23ba5a61 0x29499ea9 0x294e3739 0x294e2819 0x2fe98ee7 0x2ff16b43 0x2feb0363 0x2ff413e9 0x2feb03bb 0x2fec2cf1 0x2fee6dfd 0x2fee34fd 0x2fee2a05 0x2fee498b 0x2ff1705b 0x476ab1 0x2623d967 0x2623d7b7 0x25916513 0x23df75e5 0x23b53f3d 0x23b6821b 0x23b6792f 0x23b65d41 0x23ab4289 0x23ab407d 0x250d0af9 0x281df2c5 0x1230c8 0x23760873)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I use also this notification to pause all scene ad stop SKAudioNode action:

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(notificationPauseGame, object: nil)
    }
```

Do You Have Any Idea?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

You could try to load your file with:

```
var backgroundMusic: SKAudioNode!

if let musicURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("backgroundSound", withExtension: "mp3") {
    backgroundMusic = SKAudioNode(URL: musicURL)
    addChild(backgroundMusic)
}
```

This method give directly your audio resource without leave to `fileNamed`  to search in main bundle , it's an alternative.